# fckeditor : make a line break inside textarea plugin

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, fckeditor

I'm actually building a ckeditor v3 plugin.
The generated content is a link :

```
<a href="class" data="12456"> first line \n second line </a>
```

The text of the link has a line break and is build inside a textarea.
I can't find any information about how do I allow line break or enter key press,  inside a textarea...
Actually when i press Enter nothing happen. I think it's to prevent form submit.
Can anyone help?

Comment: I am not sure I 100% understand, but are you saying that the contents on this link is controlled by a texarea field? If I understand correctly I imagine you are using PHP to output the content inside the link. If that is the case you can use <?php echo nl2br($content); ?>. This will convert `\n` to `<br>`.

Comment: Sorry, my english doesn't look like very good. In fact i have a simple text input which helps me build the tag <a>. The content (text) is generated with a textarea. However in ckeditor the enter key inside textarea doesn't work anyway... It's a client side problem...